# Text goes over image in Chrome/Safari, not FF or IE, using Sandbags

Tags: html, css, firefox, layout, google-chrome

I am using the sandbag method to have 2 lines of text appear above an image.  Here is an image showing the effect working in FF but not in Chrome (same problem in Safari):

[image: Firefox/Chrome side-by-side]

Does anyone know what causes this?

Edit:
My apology for not posting the link: http://antigua-guide.info/ The issue can be seen halfway down the right-center column.

Here is the html and the css.

[image: html of section]

[image: css of section]

Comment: Can we have a look at it somewhere online. Or can you post the code in stead of the images

Comment: Firefox (Gecko) and Safari/Chrome (Webkit) render fonts slightly differently, which seems to be influencing your [sandbag text-wrapping technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sandbags/). It's difficult for anyone to help you unless you can post a more complete or editable HTML/CSS example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a webkit/chrome bug.  You can report it on http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list . Meanwhile you can use a dirty [chrome/safari hack](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2008/09/css-hack-for-google-chrome-and-safari-31/) to add some fixes to your css:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   .hpm2_content img, .modulebody img {
        margin-top:18px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  I adapted this solution to the various sandbags (0-5 lines above the image).  Thank you very much!

Comment: +1, This bug gave me 2 hours of blood and tear ... Gonna report it right away and will test your fix. Regards